# How I can navigate to multible sites using C# and selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

```
private const string Url1 = "https://www.w3schools.com/"
```

```
private const string Url2 = "https://www.@example.com/"
```

.
.
.

```
[Test]
public void CC1()
{
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriverWait _wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
    InitialLogin(driver, _wait);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url1);//here i want to change the link with Url2 
}
```

I want to run the test case for multile pages which take the link
and do the same opreasions on all pages instead of using

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url string");
```

again and again

Comment: Can you use a loop? Like put all sites you want to visit in an Array / List and loop them over with the logic which you shared?

Comment: in the loop/list i have to visit all the links then every time.

Comment: but i want to run the test cases. which means i dont want to visit every link over and over again.

Comment: You can put the webpage opening logic in a common function, take the webpage address as a parameter and have multiple tests with each of you websites, i.e. the number of web sites ∝ number of test cases. Call the common function from the test case.

Comment: thats what i am already doing i want to reduce the code size so that code file can also be optimiz

Comment: Why do you need to reduce the code size? Do you have a specific problem?